# Crashing with "UBM not found" when executing alizeSystem.createSpeakerModel(userName);

Tags: android, machine-learning, speech-recognition

I'm using [android-alize](https://github.com/ALIZE-Speaker-Recognition/android-alize) for a speaker identification app. As the documentation says I'm trying to train a model as below,

// Send audio to the system
alizeSystem.addAudio(audio);

// Train a model with the audio
alizeSystem.createSpeakerModel("Somebody");

But my application crashing with below stacktrace,

```
04-17 14:29:31.216 5546-5546/com.example.channa.poc_alize W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-17 14:29:31.253 5546-5546/com.example.channa.poc_alize W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
04-17 14:29:31.253 5546-5546/com.example.channa.poc_alize W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
04-17 14:29:33.184 5546-5546/com.example.channa.poc_alize I/System.out: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AAudioClipsForSpeakerRecognition%2F1%2Fspeaker_1.wav
04-17 14:29:34.155 5546-5546/com.example.channa.poc_alize W/System.err: AlizeSpkRec.AlizeException: [ Exception 0x7c4ca25480 ]
      message   = "UBM not found"
      source file = /Users/channa/Documents/Projects/Work/Sample Projects/android-alize/alize/src/main/cpp/LIA_RAL/LIA_SpkDet/SimpleSpkDetSystem/src/SimpleSpkDetSystem.cpp
      line number = 869
        at AlizeSpkRec.SimpleSpkDetSystem.createSpeakerModel(Native Method)
        at com.example.channa.poc_alize.SpeakerRecognition.trainSpeakerModel(SpeakerRecognition.java:40)
        at com.example.channa.poc_alize.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:97)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4477)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4524)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1691)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
04-17 14:29:34.182 5546-5586/com.example.channa.poc_alize D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
04-17 14:29:34.183 5546-5546/com.example.channa.poc_alize D/ViewRootImpl@52672bd[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
    MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
```

Appreciate your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further debugged the [Alize-LIA_RAL](https://github.com/ALIZE-Speaker-Recognition/LIA_RAL) and I realized that the android project looks for a world.gmm (UBM) in assets/gmm/world.gmm. Seems like we have to generate this world.gmm with LIA_RAL library and later add it to the android code.

However we have to specify the UBM location using below given code snippet during the alize initialization.

```
    InputStream backgroundModelAsset = null;
    try {
        backgroundModelAsset = context.getAssets().open("gmm/world.gmm");
        alizeSystem.loadBackgroundModel(backgroundModelAsset);
        backgroundModelAsset.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AlizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I managed to find a world.gmm from google search and when I add it to my android project, the error disappeared. However the predictions weren't accurate.

Therefore, I'm looking further into LIA_RAL source code to generate this world.gmm (UBM) by providing train data that satisfy my requirement (audio samples).